# How to view & copy iPhone photos on Mac OS X without iPhoto

Tags: macos, iphone, photos, iphoto, ilife

From Mac OS X version 10.6 onwards, Apple insists that we buy iLife for exploring photos from the iPhone.  In previous versions of OS X, I could easily explore my iPhone photos, using iPhoto directly and can easily copy.

But newer versions of Mac OS X force us to buy iLife.

Is there any alternative for exploring photos of iPhone like iPhoto in OS X?

[image]

Comment: What's preventing you from using iPhoto? An error message? It's not supposed to behave the way you describe.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You actually don't need to download anything extra at all. Apple includes an application called Image Capture as part of the default OS X install. You can use it to import pictures from your camera/iPhone, as well as scanning in photos from a scanner.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is unclear for a few reasons.  First of all, iLife is not an app, it's a package that includes iPhoto, iWeb, iMovie, and Garage Band.  Also, iPhoto is allowed and in fact is the preferred method of managing photos on your iPhone.  There's nothing about Snow Leopard that prevents this.

Perhaps you have iPhoto '08 and are having one of the following problems?  Both links lead to a problem description and potential fix:

- [Fixing syncing between iPhone and iPhoto '08](http://www.tuaw.com/2009/03/11/tuaw-tip-fixing-syncing-between-iphone-and-iphoto-08/)
- [Getting an error -50 when trying to sync my iPhoto '08 album to my iPhone](http://discussions.apple.com/message.jspa?messageID=5205715)

Comment: osx-10.6.2 onwards don't allows us to install iPhoto separately.

Comment: Did you install Mac OS X from scratch without iPhoto?  What happened to the version you had before?  It shouldn't stop working with iTunes just because you install Snow Leopard.

Comment: Yes ! I installed osx from scratch without iPhoto. now what should i do for having iPhoto back ?

Comment: Macs come with a separate Applications Install DVD that has the iLife applications (including iPhoto) on it. Do you have yours? You should be able to install from that.  If you had the app before, then at some point you had the installation media.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you try [Picasa](http://picasa.google.com/mac/)

Answer (score 1):

What version of iPhoto do you have presently installed?

iPhoto is part of iLife and if you have say iPhoto '08 (version 7.x) you can't only update iPhoto to the 2009 (version 8.x) but you have to update the entire suite. The screenshot you posted is the iPhoto Updater for iPhoto 8.1 so it requires iPhoto 8.1 to be installed.

The iLife '09 installer allows you to choose what applications you install. (Just click Customize on the Installation Type Screen)

The limitation is *not* a limitation of OS X 10.6.2+.

Comment: When I installed mac os 10.6.2 - iPhoto wasn't there inbuilt. why iPhoto isn't included as defaults ?

Comment: @sugar: iPhoto is part of iLife and not part of Mac OS X itself. If you install just Mac OS X whether it was 10.4.x, 10.5.x or 10.6.x you won't get iPhoto. New Macs include iLife with them and so iLife is on the restore DVDs as well.